# Nginx Cache alterntive where two requests can populate large cache files simultaneously?

Tags: nginx, http, cache, varnish, cdn

I am using Nginx as a caching reverse proxy for large files.

It is important to me that the origin server does not have to output more bandwidth than necessary. 
So if the download of the file gets started with two connections, I don't want nginx to download the whole file two times.

So I enabled `proxy_cache_lock` which works for that. But then the second request has to wait until the first one has finished to download the file.
This can take a long time and I want the second request to start downloading right away.

So what I need is a system where two request (which will be http range requests) can populate the same cache file, and every request only downloads its range from the origin server.

This makes only sense for large files, and thats what most systems (varnish, nginx) seem to be intended for.
Nginx works well for large files in general, but not in this situation.

Is there a caching system that could satisfy my needs or do I have to write my own?
I think some CDNs could have similar requirements.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds a lot like a torrent protocol implementation. Maybe look into delivering that way? Something like a torrent based upstream for nginx?

Comment: I have HTTP server serving files and users downloading over HTTP. I am not at liberty to change the protocols, i can only work in the middle...

Comment: If I am not mistaken trafficserver solves your problem: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TS/Partial+Object+Caching